# How do I load gziped json data into table, using Spark SQL's CREATE TABLE Query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-superset

I want to connect Apache Superset with Apache Spark (I have `Spark 3.1.2`) and Query the data on Superset's SQL Lab using Apache Spark SQL.

On spark's master, I started thrift server using this command `spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2`.

Then I added Spark cluster as a database in Superset using SQLAlchemy URI `hive://hive@spark:10000/`. I am able to access Spark cluster on Superset.

I can load JSON data as table using this SQL

```
CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS test_table
USING JSON
LOCATION "/path/to/data.json"
```

and I am able to Query data using simple SQL statements like `SELECT * FROM test_table LIMIT 10`

BUT the problem is that json data is compressed as gzipped files.

So I tried

```
CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS test_table
USING JSON
LOCATION "/path/to/data.json.gz"
```

but it did not work. **I want to know how do load gzipped json data into a table**

Comment: what is the format for data at rest you expect?

Comment: Data at rest is Newline separated json compressed as gzipped.

Answer (score 0):

**Compressed JSON storage**

If you have large JSON text you can explicitly compress JSON text using built-in COMPRESS function. In the following example compressed JSON content is stored as binary data, and we have computed column that decompress JSON as original text using DECOMPRESS function:

```
CREATE TABLE Person

( _id int identity constraint PK_JSON_ID primary key,

data varbinary(max),

value AS CAST(DECOMPRESS(data) AS nvarchar(max))

)



INSERT INTO Person(data)

VALUES (COMPRESS(@json))
```

COMPRESS and DECOMPRESS functions use standard GZip compression.

Another example:

```
CREATE EXTENSION json_fdw;
postgres=# CREATE SERVER json_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER json_fdw;

postgres=# CREATE FOREIGN TABLE customer_reviews
(
    customer_id TEXT,
    "review.date" DATE,
    "review.rating" INTEGER,
    "product.id" CHAR(10),
    "product.group" TEXT,
    "product.title" TEXT,
    "product.similar_ids" CHAR(10)[]
)
SERVER json_server
OPTIONS (filename '/home/citusdata/customer_reviews_nested_1998.json.gz');
```

Note: This example was taken from https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2013/05/30/run-sql-on-json-files-without-any-data-loads

Comment: Does this help ?